# Plupload - Fazer refresh à página

Tags: jquery, upload

É o seguinte: estou a trabalhar numa plataforma online para a empresa em que trabalho.

Nessa plataforma uso o Plupload para o upload de imagens.

Está tudo a funcionar bem, excepto uma parte.

Depois das imagens serem carregadas (100%) quero que a página seja actualizada, pois as imagens passam para um `<div>` à parte.

Já pesquisei sobre isto e sei que posso usar o `UploadComplete` e até já testei mas não acontece nada depois dos 100%.

Neste momento tenho o código simplificado só para verem como está:

```
$(function() {
    $("#uploader").plupload({
        runtimes : 'html5,html4',
        url : 'upload.php',
        resize : {
          width : 800,
          height : 500,
          quality : 90,
          crop: false
        },
        filters : {
          max_file_size : '10mb',
          mime_types: [{
             title : "Image files",
             extensions : "jpg,jpeg,gif,png"
          }]
        },
        rename: true,
        sortable: true,
        dragdrop: true,
        views: {
          list: false,
          thumbs: true,
          active: 'thumbs'
        }
     });
});
```

Assim está a funcionar, mas acredito que não esteja feito da forma mais correcta.

Na pesquisa que fiz encontrei coisas tipo `init()` e `Uploader.bind` e `var = uploader = $('#uploader').pluploadQueue();` mas se usar esses exemplos de código nem o Plupload consigo fazer aparecer.

Aceito sugestões e correcções de erros.

Answer (score 1):

Precisas de fazer bind ao evento "FileUploaded":

```
$(function() {

$("#uploader").plupload({
    runtimes: 'html5,html4',
    url: 'upload.php',
    resize: {
        width: 800,
        height: 500,
        quality: 90,
        crop: false
    },
    filters: {
        max_file_size: '10mb',
        mime_types: [{
            title: "Image files",
            extensions: "jpg,jpeg,gif,png"
        }]
    },
    rename: true,
    sortable: true,
    dragdrop: true,
    views: {
        list: false,
        thumbs: true,
        active: 'thumbs'
    }
});

var uploader = $('#uploader').pluploadQueue();

uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function() {
    if (uploader.files.length == (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
                    location.reload(); // REFRESH AO BROWSER
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Já testei com os eventos FileUpload e UploadComplete e não consegui.  
Inseri um alert dentro do evento para saber quando funciona.  
O que pode fazer com que eventos não disparem?  
Será o container do plupload?  
Será por não ter o DOCTYPE como html5?  
Será por ter outros plugins na mesma página?

Comment: Já percebi melhor isto. Se usar plupload no início e depois pluploadQueue o evento não dispara. Mas se usar pluploadQueue nas duas partes o evento já dispara. O problema aqui é que ao usar pluploadQueue o layout do plugin muda totalmente.. Como faço para resolver isso?